# jacorb 2.2.4: Compile error when building from source

Tags: jacorb

I have downloaded jacorb-2.2.4 source and when I try to build it with ant, I see following error:

> .../JacORB-2.2.4/src/org/jacorb/orb/portableInterceptor/ServerRequestInfoImpl.java:45:
> error: ServerRequestInfoImpl is not abstract and does not override
> abstract method adapter_name() in ServerRequestInfoOperations

But when I look into ServerRequestInfoOperations, I don't see any method by name 'adapter_name'.

What am I missing here?